# Return Redirect Depends on Session Language in HomeController Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying to *return redirect* the function depends on **Session Language** but getting error. Below is my function of HomeController.php

```
    public function updateCart(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->session()->get('cart')->items;
    //unset(Session::get('cart')->items[$id]);
    $arr    =   explode('_',$request->form_prdid);
    Session::get('cart')->totalQuantity =   (Session::get('cart')->totalQuantity-Session::get('cart')->items[$arr[0]][$arr[1]]['qty'])+$request->form_qty;
    Session::get('cart')->items[$arr[0]][$arr[1]]['qty']    =   $request->form_qty;
    flash()->success('Cart is successfully updated!');
    return redirect('/shopping-cart/');
}
```

I want the page to be redirected to /shopping-cart/ if default (en) language selected, but if session is second (ar) Language then it should be redirected to /ar/shopping-cart/

Comment: Are you trying to put the return redirect() inside of an if/else statement? I don't see anything in your code sample showing a reference to selected language.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes, I'm looking for some solution even it's if else statement, I tried by myself but it returns with fetal error. Do let me know how exactly we can put the if else statement in the function so I can redirect users to /shopping-cart (en) with default language or else second (ar) language will redirect users to /ar/shopping-cart.
Thanks again